# How to interact head of linkedlist outside the LinkedList class in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to solve the following problem on [algoexpert](https://www.algoexpert.io/questions/Shift%20Linked%20List):

> ### Shift Linked List
>
> Write a function that takes in the head of a Singly Linked List and an integer
> `k`, shifts the list in place (i.e., doesn't create a brand new
> list) by `k` positions, and returns its new head.
>
> Shifting a Linked List means moving its nodes forward or backward and wrapping
> them around the list where appropriate. For example, shifting a Linked List
> forward by one position would make its tail become the new head of the linked
> list.
>
> Whether nodes are moved forward or backward is determined by whether
> `k`  is positive or negative.
>
> Each `LinkedList` node has an integer `value` as well as
> a `next` node pointing to the next node in the list or to
> `None` / `null` if it's the tail of the list.
>
> You can assume that the input Linked List will always have at least one node;
> in other words, the head will never be `None` / `null`.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> head = 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 // the head node with value 0
> k = 2
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 4 -> 5 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 // the new head node with value 4
> ```

The outline that the problem gives for the code is the following:

> ```
> class LinkedList:
>     def __init__(self, value):
>         self.value = value
>         self.next = None
>
> def shiftLinkedList(head, k):
>     #Write your code here.
>     pass
> ```

I suppose my background on linked list is very limited because from every resource I've read on linked lists, the general outline for it requires the node class and to have all the methods for rotating or shifting inside the `LinkedList` class.

I assume the head parameter for the function is going to be an integer that denotes the position of the list but how do I refer the head back to the original list? I already have the code written in my Thonny editor but I wrote the function inside the `LinkedList` class and simply called for it after making my list.

For example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__self(data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def push(self, newhead):
        newnode = Node(new_data)
        newnode.next = self.head 

        self.head = newnode


 list1 = LinkedList()
 list1.head = Node(1)
 e2 = 2
 e3 = 3

 list1.head.next = e2
 e2.next = e3
```

Only once I've established my linked list can I create a method inside the class to shift or rotate it. Or am I wrong?

I tried creating a function the way the algo wanted, but I am still stuck. I think what I am really confused about is whether the argument `head` is an integer or a `LinkedList`?

Here is my complete attempt:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data #assign data
        self.next = None #initialize next as null
        

class LinkedList:
    #function to initalize the linked list object
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
            
    def moveToFront(self):
        tmp = self.head
        sec_last = None
        if not tmp or not tmp.next:
            return
        
        while tmp and tmp.next:
            sec_last = tmp
            tmp = tmp.next
        
        sec_last.next = None
        tmp.next = self.head
        self.head = tmp
        


def shiftList(head, k):
    if not head:
        return
    tmp = head
    length = 1
    while(temp.next != None):
        tmp = tmp.next
        length += 1
        
    if(k>length):
        k = k%length
    
    k = length - k
    
    
    if(k==0 or k==length):
        return head
    current = head
    cmt = 1
    while(cmt < k and current != None):
        current = current.next
        cmt += 1
    
    if(current==None):
        return head
    kthnode = current
    tmp.next = head
    head = kthnode.next
    kthnode.next = None
    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the head parameter for the function is going to be an integer that denotes the position of the list

No, the head of a list is a `LinkedList` instance. So `head.value` is the value of the first node in the list, and `head.next` is a reference to the second node in the list.

In your attempt you have changed the definition of `LinkedList` from the original, and created another class, called `Node`, which really is what `LinkedList` is supposed to be (except that you call a property `data` instead of `value`). It is understandable that you did this, as you wanted to have a kind of container class for the *whole* linked list, and reserve a separate class `Node` for what concerns a single node in that list. But this code challenge does not work with such a container class.

It just works with one class that represents a node, but through its `next` member the whole list is inferred from it. Moreover, they want the function to return a reference to the node that has become the head of the list once the shifting has completed. This is a different way of working than with a container class, in which you would *mutate* the `head` member, and would not return anything: the caller would just access the list through the modified `head` member.

So, what you intended to do is not inherently wrong, it just is not the data structure that this code challenge is working with. You should go with it.

> what I am really confused about is whether the argument 'head' is an integer or a linkedlist

It is a node, but the list is inferred from it. It can be a bit confusing that they call their class `LinkedList` and not `Node`, but it is a matter of how you look at it.

So here is how you could solve it:

- First find out what the last node is in the list. For this you will have to start from the head (you have nothing else) and step through the list until you bump into its end. Also maintain a counter so that at the end you know how many nodes there are in the list.
- Then create a link from that tail node to the head node, so that the list now becomes circular: it has no end anymore
- Find out which node comes k steps *before* the tail node in this cyclic list. As it is not possible to walk backwards in a list, you should actually walk size-k steps forward, and so you need the size of the list which you determined in the first step.
- The node *after* that found node should become the head node.
- Make that node itself the new tail node: break the link it has with the node after it (the new head).
- Return the new head reference

One more thing should be done to protect this code against *huge* values for *k*. Let's say the list has 6 elements, and *k* is 600, then of course it makes no sense to run over the cyclic list 600 times, as we can predict that you'll end where you started! 600 is a multiple of 6... So to make this efficient, you need to reduce *k* to a number that is less than the size of the list. The formula for knowing how many steps forward you need to take is `-k % size`.

Here is the implementation of this idea:

```
def shiftLinkedList(head, k):
    if not head:
        return  # Nothing to do
    # Determine size of the list, and its tail node
    size = 1
    tail = head
    while tail.next:
        size += 1
        tail = tail.next
    
    # Temporarily make the list cyclic
    tail.next = head
    # Find out where to cut the cycle
    for _ in range(-k % size):
        tail = tail.next
    head = tail.next
    # Cut the cycle
    tail.next = None
    return head
```